# Password holding different data (phpMyAdmin Database)

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, passwords

`password varchar(120)`

Above is the `column name` and `datatype` for the password that I set. I am using phpMyAdmin Database and created a user for testing purpose with **userTest** as username and **user123** as password. When I checked back the database, instead of holding **user123** as password, it holds something like **0dcbd056919392554f346a10cc114d27**. Compared to SQL Server Database, SQL Server Database will hold the exact data for password that user entered through registration.

Even so, I still can login using the **user123** as password for the username **userTest**. If I used the **0dcbd056919392554f346a10cc114d27** as password, I unable to login into the system. I've just notice it and started to wonder, as an admin, how am I going to know the user password exactly like the one that they used to register, if I going through the database?

Comment: How are you creating the user account? Since you're storing in a standard varchar and using phpMyAdmin to do the insert, the password should be stored in plaintext — which means you're running a function or some other means to hash the password before inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Why on Earth would you need to know a user's password? This is a truly awful idea. I explicitly don't want to know my user's passwords, or have the means to decrypt them. There are many reasons why this is a bad idea, one of them is that if a user re-uses passwords and your database is compromised, then the user's plaintext password has been compromised.

What is much more common is to hash the password; taking the user's password, combined with a cryptographic salt, and enter those as input to a hash function (I believe bcrypt is most common these days, but your requirements may vary). The function returns some nonsense string like $2a$06$XKJbhsfB4q53MovNJRgEuOkQKpnOIpjfQ7P8qMUWa63qGeHnPlyMu which you then store in the database. When the user tries to log in, you repeat the hash process and compare the result to the value stored in the database.

If you really have a business need to store the plaintext password, then I highly recommend warning the users in plain language that their database is going to be stored by an insecure means and to absolutely use a specially-crafted password just for your application.

Again, I strongly recommend not storing the passwords in plain text and making sure you have a cryptographically secure hash in place.

But anyway, to directly answer your question, you're not storing a plain text value here. I can't know what you're doing when you're inserting the user's password, but clearly you're performing some function on the varchar field. Probably you've selected one of the functions from the dropdown in the phpMyAdmin insert page (see screenshot below); this applies the selected MySQL function to the data as you insert it. There's probably not another good reason for phpMyAdmin to be mangling your data like this, so that seems most likely.

[image: phpMyAdmin function dropdown]